# Sharing Computation of Force in Haskell

Tags: haskell, simulation, physics

I'm implementing a N-Body simulation in Haskell. https://github.com/thorlucas/N-Body-Simulation

Right now, each particle calculates its Force, then acceleration against each other particle. In other words, *O(n²)* computations of force. I could reduce this down to O(n choose 2) if I were to calculate each combination once.

```
let combs = [(a, b) | (a:bs) <- tails ps, b <- bs ]
    force = map (\comb -> gravitate (fst comb) (snd comb)) combs
```

But I cant figure out how to apply these to the particles without using state. In the above example, `ps` is `[Particle]` where

```
data Particle = Particle Mass Pos Vel Acc deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Theoretically, in an stateful language I would simply be able to loop through the combinations, calculate the relevant acceleration from the force from each `a` and `b`, then update each `Particle` in `ps` acceleration as I do that.

I've thought about doing something like `foldr f ps combs`. The starting accumulator would be the current `ps` and `f` would be some function that takes each `comb` and updates the relevant `Particle` in `ps`, and returns that accumulator. That seems really memory intensive and quite complicated for such a simple process.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try storing your results in a lazy `Map (Particle, Particle) Force` and [tying the knot](https://wiki.haskell.org/Tying_the_Knot)

Comment: Note that _O_ (_n_ · (_n_ ­– 1)) ≡ _O_ (_n²_). Calculating each force only once won't save you from getting abysmal performance for anything you could seriously call _many_-body simulation. To really save on asymptotic cost in this kind of computation, you need an approximation method; this is [usually done with something octree-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes%E2%80%93Hut_simulation).

Comment: Thanks! @leftaroundabout. Somebody actually edited my post. I was incorrect before but I think the editor is incorrect as well. The actual O notation would be O(n choose 2), or O(n!/(2(n-2)!). Right? I was considering implementing approximation after I had fixed this sharing computation.

Comment: @ThorCorreia: O(n!/(2(n-2)!)) = O(n!/(n-2)!) = O(n · (n - 1)) = O(n²)

Comment: I don't quite follow @Ryan. Take for example 200 choose 2. That's 19,900, whereas 200(199) is 39,800. That's nearly twice the computations. As this scales, the difference becomes even more dramatic. 2,000 choose 2 is only about 2e6, while 2000(1999) is 4e6.

Comment: @ThorCorreia `O` (pronounced "big oh") notation isn't actually the number of computations for a certain input. It's how the number of computations scales as n goes to infinity. Another way of thinking about it is "what eventually dominates when n gets big". Probably too much to go in depth in a comment though!

Comment: @ThorCorreia At scale, we don't care about constant multipliers. "Twice as many" is fairly harmless if it's always "twice as many". The difference between, say, O(n) and O(2^n), is that if you double the input size, the former doubles in time, whereas if you even add one to the input size, the latter doubles in time. It's a matter of scale, not of actual quantity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the code from https://github.com/thorlucas/N-Body-Simulation

```
updateParticle :: Model -> Particle -> Particle
updateParticle ps p@(Particle m pos vel acc) =
    let accs = map (gravitate p) ps
        acc' = foldr (\(accx, accy) (x, y) -> (accx + x, accy + y)) (0, 0) accs
        vel' = (fst vel + fst acc, snd vel + snd acc)
        pos' = (fst pos + fst vel, snd pos + snd vel)
    in  Particle m pos' vel' acc'

step :: ViewPort -> Float -> Model -> Model
step _ _ ps = map (updateParticle ps) ps
```

and modifying it so the accelerations are worked out in a matrix (well, list of lists...) separately from updating each particle, we get...

```
updateParticle :: Model -> (Particle, [Acc]) -> Particle
updateParticle ps (p@(Particle m pos vel acc), accs) =
    let acc' = foldr (\(accx, accy) (x, y) -> (accx + x, accy + y)) (0, 0) accs
        vel' = (fst vel + fst acc, snd vel + snd acc)
        pos' = (fst pos + fst vel, snd pos + snd vel)
    in  Particle m pos' vel' acc'

step :: ViewPort -> Float -> Model -> Model
step _ _ ps = map (updateParticle ps) $ zip ps accsMatrix where
    accsMatrix = [map (gravitate p) ps | p <- ps]
```

... so the problem is essentially how to reduce the number of calls to `gravitate` when working out `accsMatrix`, using the fact that `gravitate a b` = `-1 * gravitate b a`.

If we were to print out `accsMatrix`, it would look like...

```
[[( 0.0,  0.0), ( 1.0,  2.3), (-1.0,  0.0), ...
[[(-1.0, -2.3), ( 0.0,  0.0), (-1.2,  5.3), ...
[[( 1.0,  0.0), ( 1.2, -5.3), ( 0.0,  0.0), ...
...
```

... so we see `accsMatrix !! i !! j == -1 * accsMatrix !! j !! i`.

So to use the above fact we need access to some indexes. Firstly, we index the outer list...

```
accsMatrix = [map (gravitate p) ps | (i,p) <- zip [0..] ps]
```

... and replace the inner list with a list comprehension...

```
accsMatrix = [[ gravitate p p' | p' <- ps] | (i,p) <- zip [0..] ps]
```

... get some more indexes available via zip...

```
accsMatrix = [[ gravitate p p' | (j, p') <- zip [0..] ps] | (i,p) <- zip [0..] ps]
```

... and then, the key, is make `accsMatrix` depend on itself for half of the matrix...

```
accsMatrix = [[ if i == j then 0 else if i < j then gravitate p p' else -1 * accsMatrix !! j !! i | (j, p') <- zip [0..] ps] | (i, p) <- zip [0..] ps]
```

We can split it up a bit as well, as below...

```
accsMatrix = [[ accs (j, p') (i, p) | (j, p') <- zip [0..] ps] | (i, p) <- zip [0..] ps]
accs (j, p') (i, p) 
    | i == j    = 0
    | i < j     = gravitate p p'
    | otherwise = -1 * accsMatrix !! j !! i
```

... or avoid list comprehensions by using `map`

```
accsMatrix = map (flip map indexedPs) $ map accs indexedPs  
indexedPs = zip [0..] ps
accs (i, p) (j, p')
    | i == j    = 0
    | i < j     = gravitate p p'
    | otherwise = -1 * accsMatrix !! j !! i
```

... or by using the list monad...

```
accsMatrix = map accs indexedPs >>= (:[]) . flip map indexedPs
```

... although it's harder (for me) to see what's going on in these.

There are probably some horrible performance issues with this list of lists approach, especially using `!!`, and the fact that you're still running *O(n²)* operations due to the traversals, and the fact that O (n · (n ­– 1)) ≡ O (n²) as @leftaroundabout mentioned, but each iteration should call `gravitate` `n * (n-1) / 2` times.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I think the actual O would be O(n choose 2), or O(n!/(2(n-2)!). For example, for "abcd", the combinations would be "ab","ac","ad","bc","bd","cd". 4 choose 2 is 6. That's a lot less than 4^2 = 16. But you're right the performance would still be bad.

Comment: Ah you're right! I was out by a factor of two? I have tweaked my answer to specify `n * (n-1) / 2` which I think is n choose 2, and added a test for the leading diagonal case to not call `gravitate`

Comment: awesome. I'll take a deeper look at your code once a have a bit more time. Thanks!